# Azure KeyVault corrupts PFX certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I have a TLS certificate received from a public CA that is in pem format without the intermediate certs included. I need the certificate in PFX format with intermediate certs in Azure KeyVault to use with an Application Gateway.

I am able to successfully add the intermediate certs and convert to PFX format with the following:

```
$apiCertSecret | openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -out /tmp/cert.pfx -CAfile /tmp/certchain.pem -chain `
  -macalg sha256 -certpbe aes-256-cbc -keypbe aes-256-cbc
```

Where `$apiCertSecret` is the raw text of the original cert and `/tmp/certchain.pem` is the root and intermediate cert in PEM format.

The resulting PFX cert checks out AFAICT as valid with both certutil and openssl. Both `certutil cert.pfx`, run on Windows, and `openssl pkcs12 -info -nokeys -in /tmp/cert.pfx`, run in WSL, run without error and show all the intermediate certs.

When I take the `cert.pfx` file and upload it to Azure KeyVault via the portal or via `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate`, I end up with an unusable cert. If I reference it from KeyVault in the Application Gateway configuration, I get an `unrecognized name` error when connecting to that listener. This is the full error from using `openssl s_client -connect` to test:

```
error:0A000458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 112
```

If I retrieve the secret from KeyVault with `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -AsPlainText` and pipe it to `| openssl pkcs12 -info -nokeys` I get the following error:

```
140606285837632:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140606285837632:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS12
```

Importing this same cert directly into the Application Gateway works without issue. It also imports into the Windows cert store without issue although I haven't attempted to use it on a site there. I am looking to complete the automation of a cert upgrade, but I'm at a loss for what else to try. I would prefer to reference the cert from Azure KeyVault so the Application Gateway will automatically pick up changes, but right now that appears to be the issue.

My questions.

1. Are there any other commands I should use to inspect the certificate I have that might shed a little more light on the issue?
2. Is there another way I should attempt to upload the certificate to Azure KeyVault that would avoid the "corruption"?
3. Any chance someone has seen this as a known issue in Azure KeyVault?

In case it matters, the version of openssl in use is `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-8.2.0#examples get-azkeyvaultsecret returns the PFX/P12 **in base64** but OpenSSL doesn't support that -- try `| openssl base64 -d | openssl pkcs12 -info ...`.

Comment: In some cases when you want to get the certificate and its privtate key out of azure keyvault, then you need to get it out of AKV as a secret and not as a cert. Getting the cert from AKV only returns the public key.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good call out on base64 decoding when doing the check. Even with the decode it still throws and error: `error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:101`

@ToreNestenius The secret is being retrieved with `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`

Comment: Hmm -- is this returned as 'single-line' base64? `openssl base64 -d` mishandles lines it considers too long -- without giving an error. If it is one line try breaking it into chunks of 76 or less, or (probably easier) instead use `[Convert]::FromBase64String` as in the example on the page I linked. Also FYI only one atsign 'ping' per comment is supported, so you might want to respond separately to the other person.

Comment: Did you manage to find out why the application gateway listener was unable to return your certificate? Using `openssl s_client -connect` I get the exact same error, though piping `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` through to `| base64 -d | openssl pkcs12 -info` does work for me. Because of this, I don't think it's actually the key vault corrupting the certificate, rather I expect some networking / auth issue between the gateway & keyvault. Unfortunately, I'm unable to directly add the certificate to the application gateway due to policies.

Comment: @Pudding I did not. I ended up manually converting it and storing it as a base64 secret and using that in my template.